# Atualizar data somando no banco

Tags: php, mysql, data

Bom dia, galera.

Eu tenho no meu banco campos DATE para 'data inicial' e 'data final', para que eu possa pesquisar por intervalos. Quando importei esses dados algumas datas estavam vazias ou inconformes e não foram registradas corretamente.

Eu gostaria de saber: há alguma forma de eu selecionar os campos 'data final' do meu banco e onde ele for vazio e torná-lo igual ao 'data inicial' + 30(dias), fazendo-o pelo próprio mysql ou terei que utilizar o php?

Valeu!

Comment: Quando você diz "vazio" se refere ao campo nulo, certo?

Comment: Sim, o campo estava vazio na planilha e entrou no banco como NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar um **UPDATE** para atualizar o campo data final quando que ele estiver NULO.

Assim:

```
UPDATE minha_tabela
   SET data_final = DATE_ADD(data_inicial ,INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 WHERE data_final IS NULL;
```

Isso diretamente no banco, sem precisar de uma aplicação.

Sobre a função **DATE_ADD**:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: A solução é dar update no campo? E quando ele precisar saber quais campos foram importados com erro vai fazer o que?

Comment: Amigo, posso ter entendido errado, mas se ele quiser corrigir os dados da importação utiliza o `UPDATE`. Se ele quiser apenas contornar o problema quando for ler os dados, então usa o `COALESCE` como você sugeriu. Acredito que eu entendi uma coisa e você outra. Só o autor poderá esclarecer o que ele realmente gostaria de fazer.

Comment: Emerson, funcionou perfeitamente! Era exatamente o que eu precisava. Não conhecia essa função date_add().

O que fiz foi:
UPDATE caixa
   SET data_fin = DATE_ADD(data_ini ,INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 WHERE data_fin is NULL and data_ini is not null;

E o inverti  o where para fazer o mesmo com as datas iniciais vazias.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Atualizei a resposta com link da documentação do **DATE_ADD**, no caso de você querer saber mais.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode sim fazer direto pelo banco e sem precisar mudar os dados da sua tabela.

Use a função [**`coalesce`**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php). Ela tenta obter o valor mais a esquerda da expressão e caso ele seja nulo é retornado o valor a direita.

```sql
SELECT DATA_INICIAL, COALESCE(DATA_FINAL, DATE_ADD(DATA_INICIAL, INTERVAL 30 DAY))
FROM TABELA
WHERE CONDICAO
```

[Documentação do coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)